# Dynatable from ajax sort not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dynatable

I'm trying to load json with [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/) The data looks good, but can't sort, what is the problem?

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var dynatable = $('table').dynatable({
              dataset: {
                ajax: true,
                ajaxOnLoad: true,
                ajaxUrl: 'people.json',
                records: [],
                perPageDefault: 4,
                perPageOptions: [4,6,8,10]
              },
              params: {
                records: 'People'
              }
            }).data("dynatable");

    });
```

And the table:

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>ADDRESS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your table html tag to

```
<table id="myTable">
```

change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dynatable({
         dataset: {
            ajax: true,
            ajaxOnLoad: true,
            ajaxUrl: 'people.json',
            records: [],
            perPageDefault: 4,
            perPageOptions: [4,6,8,10]
          },
          params: {
            records: 'People'
          }
        });
});
```